# Populate Realm's IList with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, realm, automapper

I have a source type

```
public class A
{
    public List<string> MyList {get; set;}
}
```

and a destination type which extends `RealmObject`

```
public class B: RealmObject
{
    public IList<string> MyList {get;}
}
```

I need to convert `A` to `B` with Automapper. However, because `MyList` in `B` is get only, it stays empty after conversion. As I understand, Realm internally creates instance of that list and I need to add items to it (instead of assigning new list). How can I configure this with Automapper?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?#usedestinationvalue

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu tried to use "UseDestinationvalue" but it did not help. The result list is still empty.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Answer (score 2):

To make that task possible you need to use `UseDestinationvalue` to prevent creation of the list (as suggested by @Lucian Bargaoanu) and then `MapFrom` to map values.

```
public class A
{
    public List<string> MyList {get; set;}
}

public class B: RealmObject
{
    public IList<string> MyList {get;}
}

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MyList, opt =>
            {
                 opt.UseDestinationValue();
                 opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyList);
            });
    }
```